# Как использовать функцию на C в программе на NASM?

Tags: c, nasm

У меня есть файл blackbox-26.obj, в котором функция int purposelike(int a, int b), написанная на Си. Нужно написать программу на ассемблере(NASM), где бы я добавила через push два аргумента и вызвала эту самую функцию, далее работала бы с eax (куда передался ответ от функции). Но как я это могу сделать?
Пробовала писать так:

```
...
extern purposelike
...
section .text
global start
start:

push dword 456
push dword 123
call purposelike
...
```

потом nasm -f win32 l6.asm в cmd.
Но при golink /console /entry:start l6.obj msvcrt.dll возникает ошибка

```
Error!
The following symbol was not defined in the object file or files:-
purposelike
Output file not made
```

Comment: Про `blackbox-26.obj` не стоит забывать.

Comment: @user7860670, да, вы правы, просто сделать вот так golink /console /entry:start l6.obj blackbox-26.obj msvcrt.dll, спасибо)